# Weird JavaScript code to decode

Tags: javascript

I found the following weird code on a website and would like to know about it purpose. Can any help me in understanding the purpose of the the following code:

```
    (function(){
            var sourceWebappPromoID=5081743;
            var payloadType=3;
            var  zweiback_xsrf_token='';
            var gaia_xsrf_token='';
            google.promos.mobileLink.init(
                 sourceWebappPromoID,payloadType,'hpplink');
     })();
```

Comment: what is weird in that are you taking about function ?

Comment: it defines 4 variables then invokes a function.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand the weird thing for you is why `function` wrapped with curly brackets and after that "weird" `();`

That technique called [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression or simply IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)
After reviewing article you would became more familiar with code in question.

If IIFE clear for you and the question is how  `google.promos` it's too little information to assist you. Try to find link from which that library downloaded or `js` code where it's defined and look for init method of that object(`google.promos`).